powershell function security to limit who is able to call this function - from allowed functions only?
I want to limit some powershell functions, so it is possible to call them only from allowed functions, but not from any function in script code and not by calling directly.
Let's say I have 3 functions:
# Major function to be called directly in script code as user implements
function Cleanup-Collection {
    param (
        [string]$CollectionName
    )
    $Collection = Get-Collection -Name $CollectionName
    Cleanup-CollectionReferences -Collection $Collection
}

# Helper sub-function, which can be called only from Cleanup-Collection
function Cleanup-CollectionReferences {
    param (
        [PSObject]$Collection
    )
    $AllowedFunctionsAndHashes = @{...}
    If($PSScript.InvokerFunction -match $AllowedFunctionsAndHashes -And $PSScript.InvokerChecksum -match $AllowedFunctionsAndHashes[FunctionName].Hash) {
       Continue-Script
       ...
    }
}

# Test function
function Test-RestrictedFunctionCall {
    param (
        [string]$CollectionName
    )
    $Collection = Get-Collection -Name $CollectionName
    Cleanup-CollectionReferences -Collection $Collection
}

# Test invocation from script
Cleanup-CollectionReferences -Collection $Collection

Test function call and Test invocation from script should fail with exception.
The questions are:

Is it possible to limit/restrict function invocation in powershell in the manner I have described?
I know that I can do like this:
Function A {
code
Function B {
otherCode
}
}


But I don't like this, because I will get 3 screens long large main function with sub-functions with too much of indentation and this makes navigation and viewing code not convenient.

Is it possible to make powershell function Sealed except for encapsulation into separate powershell module?
I know that this is from OOP concept of classes. So should I re-design code architecture to be based on classes and then implement type-checking and maybe some other additional things?
Doesn't powershell treat functions also as objects?

By sealed I mean to have maybe some kind of checksum embedded, so that if it was modified it will fail when called until checksum or signature is rebuilt.
If signature for powershell script is implemented at the end of file with just commented string, can't these signatures be implemented on per-function basis? Not for powershell script file signature properties, but for internal validation inside the script that functions are unchanged and function-signature is valid? I just don't want to split this into many files and prefer to have one file as a library, and the best to have just one file.
Thank you in advance.
Most important is first question as I was not able to find in search engines anything related.
Yes, I know it would be easier to encapsulate and sign a library instead of this obscure logic, but really wanted to have one file and kind of close to fool-proof implementation.

this is an anti pattern in powershell. if you want to get the caller you could use (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command then check if it is within your $allowedCommands and throw if not but again, anti pattern

Not sure I fully understand your environment/situation.  Consider this: "If a script module does not include an Export-ModuleMember command, the functions and aliases in the script module are exported, but the variables are not. When a script module includes Export-ModuleMember commands, only the members specified in the Export-ModuleMember commands are exported." Export-ModuleMember limits access to only the functions you explicitly make available.

If this is Windows, you should be able to create a module file with permissions so that only your Windows account can modify/edit the module file, but make sure all other users still have read permissions set so they can have read access and still use it.  If you know how to write in C#, you could create a DLL with public functions for processing data, and private sub functions for hidden work.  I think you can do all of this from Add-Type in PowerShell (Create/save DLL, and later load/use DLL), but haven't tried this yet.

Santiago Squarzon, of course this is anti-pattern. I was asking out of curiosity and desire to learn about powershell limits. I can stick to private sub-functions to encapsulate them.  I just don't like extra indentation they would have, but that one Tab is not so big problem.

Updated Version:
The original answer was somewhat thrown together as I experimented, this version is a little more refined.  This function can be used to encrypt a module as Base64 and then generate a new module with the original module (in Base64 form) embedded.  The new module, when imported, will recreated a temporary copy of the original module, import it, and then delete the temporary copy.  All Export-ModuleMember lines from the original module should be appended to the end of the generated module.
This version differs from the original version in the following ways:

The Function's name is New-Base64Module.
It generates a new module file instead of trying edit an existing module.
The function checks if the module file to generate already exists, and if it does, it will only replace the file if the file has a special signature.
Its first parameter takes the path where you want the public encrypted module created, and second parameter takes the path for the private source module.
The private source module file is read twice.

First time to extract Export-ModuleMember commands that will be appended to the public module.
Second time to get a byte for byte copy that is converted into Base64 string which is embedded in the public module.



function New-Base64Module {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string]$Base64ModulePath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
      [string]$SourceModulePath
   )
   $Signature = '<#--Generated_Public_Base64_Module--#>'
   if ((Test-Path $Base64ModulePath -PathType Leaf) -and (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $Base64ModulePath) -notmatch $Signature) {
      throw @"
The module at '$Base64ModulePath' exists but is missing a valid signature.
To resolve this issue, you have the following options:
1. Manually delete the existing module file and rerun the function to generate a new module.
2. Correct the signature in the existing module file to match the expected signature.
3. Or point this function to a previously generated module file that has the correct signature.
"@
   }
   else {
      $ModuleCode = @'
   {0}
$PSCode = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('{1}'))

$tempModulePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$tempModulePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($tempModulePath, '.psm1')
$PSCode | Out-File -FilePath $tempModulePath -Encoding UTF8
Import-Module -Name $tempModulePath
Remove-Item -Path $tempModulePath

{2}
'@
      $RegEx = '(?mi)(?<=^\s*)export-modulemember\s+.*?(?=\s*$)'
      $PSMod = (Get-Content -LiteralPath $SourceModulePath | Select-String $Regex -AllMatches).Matches.Value -join [Environment]::NewLine
      $B64Str = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourceModulePath))
      Set-Content -Path $Base64ModulePath -Value ($ModuleCode -f $Signature, $B64Str, $PSMod)
   }
}

The following example use will create the module file ModuleWithSecretPS.psm1 located in a sub folder ModulePath, and uses ModuleSourceCode.psm1 for the source module that is converted to base64 and embedded in ModuleWithSecretPS.psm1.
New-Base64Module "$PSScriptRoot\ModulePath\ModuleWithSecretPS.psm1" "$PSScriptRoot\ModuleSourceCode.psm1"

Things to consider:

This does not prevent skilled users from decrypting the file and reading the source code.  It makes it difficult enough that most people will not bother.

A skilled person could still gain access to the source code, re-write their own version, and use it in their own scripts.


This is something I've never seen done and since I've never used this before, I really don't know what hidden problems may exist in temporarily creating a module, importing it, and then deleting it.
For a more secure method of protecting your code, I would suggest using a PSCmdlet written in C#.  If you look at this answer, you can see that the PSCmdlet is made available on the fly as it is piped into Import-Module.

I haven't tried this yet, but in theory you should be able to pipe it into something else , convert that something else to Base64 or CliXml, store it as a string in a module, and then from that module convert it back and pipe it to Import-Module as needed.



Original Answer:
NOTE: This is kind of a crazy scheme, but it appears to work.  This isn't exactly what you asked for, but does provides similar functionality.
NOTE: This is totally experimental, and just some random idea that I just now came up with.
This scheme involves 4 files:

A private module file with your desired code. Users never have this file.
The module file you make available publicly, and is semi-generated from the private module.
A script used to alter the public module to include an encrypted copy of the private module.
The script the user has, and uses import module to import the public module.

This is an example private module with a hidden Get-CallerScriptName and Get-CallerPSScriptRoot functions, and the publicly available Write-LogEntry function.  The Write-LogEntry function calls Get-CallerPSScriptRoot to get the equivalent to user's $PSScriptRoot value. The function Get-CallerPSScriptRoot calls Get-CallerScriptName, which works backwards up the PSCallStack until it finds a file that is different than the current script file. When Write-LogEntry gets the $CallerPSScriptRoot value, it then uses it to write a log entry to a log file in the caller's script's folder.
NOTE: Export-ModuleMember is required to make Write-LogEntry available to the Public module.
function Get-CallerScriptName {
   $ThisFile = $MyInvocation.ScriptName
   $Index = 0
   $ParentFile = ''
   do {
      $ParentFile = (Get-PSCallStack)[++$Index].ScriptName
   } until ( $ParentFile -ne $ThisFile  )
   return $ParentFile
}
function Get-CallerPSScriptRoot {
   Split-Path -Path (Get-CallerScriptName) -Parent
}

function Write-LogEntry([string]$Entry) {
   $CallerPSScriptRoot = Get-CallerPSScriptRoot
   $Entry | Out-File -LiteralPath "$CallerPSScriptRoot\Entries.log" -Append
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Write-LogEntry

This is the public module.  The first line is where an encoded version of the private module will be stored.  When ran, $Base64 will be assigned the encrypted text.  $PSCode will contain the decrypted text.  This code creates a temporary module file, saves the module's text to that temporary file, imports the temporary module, and removes the temporary module.
NOTE: Removing the temporary module does not appear to cause problems.  It appears that PowerShell loads the module in memory and never access it again. BUT, this may not be true and this may be a cause for problems.  So you may need to remove the line that removes the temporary module file.
NOTE: Export-ModuleMember is required to make Write-LogEntry available to the user's script.
$Base64 = 'Random text that will get replaced'
$PSCode = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64))

$tempModulePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$tempModulePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($tempModulePath, ".psm1")
$PSCode | Out-File -FilePath $tempModulePath -Encoding UTF8
Import-Module -Name $tempModulePath
Remove-Item -Path $tempModulePath

Export-ModuleMember -Function Write-LogEntry

This is the script used to encrypt the private module and embed it in the public module.  It uses RegEx to find and replace the text in the quoted string with the base64 encoded private module's text.
function Add-Base64PowerShell {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
      [string]$PSModulePath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
      [string]$PSSourcePath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
      [string]$PSCodeVar = 'Base64'
   )
   $RegEx = "(?mi)(?<=^\s*\x24$PSCodeVar\s*=\s*')([^\r\n']|'')*(?='\s*$)"
   $B64Str = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($PSSourcePath))
   $PSModText = (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $PSModulePath) -replace $RegEx, $B64Str
   Set-Content -Path $PSModulePath -Value $PSModText
}

Add-Base64PowerShell "$PSScriptRoot\OneFileWithSecretPS1.psm1" "$PSScriptRoot\ModuleSourceCode.psm1"

This is an example user script that imports the public module, which in turn decrypts the private module and imports it.  This script then uses Write-LogEntry to write an entry to the log file.
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\OneFileWithSecretPS1.psm1"

Write-LogEntry "This is a test log entry. #4"

To use this scheme:

Make modifications to the private module.
Run the code to encrypt and embed the private module in the public module.
Replace the old public module the users have with the new public module.
Verify the user's code is seeing the changes made to the private module.


Interesting idea. And if I assign, let's say, temporary Special permissions on a %Temp% folder as - Everyone - Deny Delete Files/Folders. This decrypted module will stay there, right?

@VadimK., yes, if the folder has only read permissions for everyone else, while you keep modify/full control for yourself, the contents of the folder, including the module, would become modifiable only by you.  But keep in mind that everyone can still read the public module, and a skilled programmer can easy decrypt, and read, the private module's content.  At that point, they could still create their own ps1 script using your code.  For better protection, a C# DLL would make more sense, relatively few people will try to hack a DLL, but it is also more effort on your part.

@VadimK. FYI: Added function called New-Base64Module that takes an original module you give it and converts it to Base64, and then generates a new module with the Base64 version embedded.
